# Finding an element in an unchanging list with a given name

Tags: java, data-structures

In Java, I'm making a collection of objects (of the same type), each of which contains a String field called `name`. The collection, the objects, and their`name`s are all made in the constructor, never to be changed. I want to be able to easily find the object with a given `name`.

```
class Program { 
    final Collection<Foo> foos; 

    Program() {
        foos = new HashSet<>();   // Note: I'm willing to use another type of collection
        foos.add(new Foo("First", 7));
        foos.add(new Foo("Qwerty", 4));
    }

    get(String name) {
        // how?
    }
}

class Foo {
    final String name;
    int size;

    Foo(String name, int size) {
         this.name = name;
         this.size = size;
    }
}
```

I can think of a few ways of getting the Foo with the given `name`. I can make a `Map<String,Foo>`, but this seems to use a lot more memory than really needed (each String must be duplicated in memory, and there's a whole new data structure in place). Alternatively, I can make a simple foreach loop, but this is O(n) efficiency, and I'm looking for O(1) or close to it.

Comment: Note that a `HashSet` uses a `HashMap` behind the scenes.

Comment: Use a `Map` instead of `Set`. @SotiriosDelimanolis any `Set` uses a `Map` behind the scenes.

Comment: `Set`s aren't really made for retrieval.

Comment: Note that you can create any kind of `Set` from a `Map` implementation: [`Collections#newSetFromMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap(java.util.Map)).

Comment: Do you really need all that you are looking for? You might avoid unnecessary waste of time by following the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: Are the name field values unique among your objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as pointed out in the comments, [the implementation of `HashSet` actually uses a `HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), so don't expect the set to be more memory efficient.

Secondly, you claim that the `String` instances must be duplicated when using a map. This is *not* true. Java passes instances of non-primitive types by reference, not by value, so if you create the mapping like this:

```
map.put(foo.getName(), foo);
```

the `String` instance that your `name` field in `Foo` points to will be the exact same instance that the key of the map will point to. You are not wasting any memory. Note also that [the JVM will reuse string literals](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3), so even something like this:

```
map.put("alice", new Foo("alice"));
```

will not result in the strings being duplicated in memory. In general, you should be careful about making too many assumptions like this, because not only the JVM, but also the compiler, may make a lot of optimizations behind your back. Focus on functionality and readability, then optimize later if you spot a bottleneck. *Insert cliché saying about premature optimization.*

Finally, the `Collection` interface provides no `get` method, because it wouldn't make any sense. A collection is just that, a collection of objects. It doesn't know anything about them, it just "collects" them. Retrieving an object from an arbitrary collection would be the same as asking someone to open a drawer of unknown items and take out the blue thing in it. Said person would have to look at each item to find the blue one, but there may be multiple blue things, so not only does it take linear time to find a blue thing, there may also be duplicates (not in a `Set` though), and if so, you may not know *which* blue thing you get.

Now, a `Map` on the other hand provides a means of associating some sort of unique identifier with each item it "collects" (note that a `Map` is *not* a `Collection`, though). This is exactly what you are trying to manually implement in your `Program` class. You want a collection of `Foo` objects, and you want to uniquely identify them by name. That is what a map is for.

Note that if you want to support duplicates and just get *some* `Foo` with a given name, you are looking for a *multimap*, which you can make a very rough implementation of by mapping names to *lists* of `Foo` objects (note that you'll have to do the necessary null checks and list instantiations yourself):

```
Map<String,List<Foo>> map = ...;
```

If you insist on using a `Collection`, you will have to iterate it to retrieve an object (because the `Collection` interface makes no guarantees about iteration order). In general, though, use collections for situations where you need *membership tests* (I have this `Foo`, does it exist in my collection?), and maps for situations where you need to retrieve objects given a unique identifier.